# Reading from an RSS news feed and inserting them into Drupal's Database

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7

Is there any drupal plugin or code that allows you to read from an external RSS feed (lets say cnn.com/rss) and insert the content posts into the drupal database as content nodes?

I need this to be automatic. Meaning regularly updating the Drupal database every time a news post on cnn.com takes place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the [Feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) is used for this.  From the project page:

> Import or aggregate data as nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple
>   database records.
>
> - One-off imports and periodic aggregation of content
> - Import or aggregate RSS/Atom feeds
> - Import or aggregate CSV files
> - Import or aggregate OPML files
> - PubSubHubbub support
> - Create nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple database records from import
> - Extensible to import any other kind of content
> - Granular mapping of input elements to Drupal content elements
> - Exportable configurations
> - Batched import for large files